# C Animated Roulette Wheel

Tags: c, animation

For class I have been tasked with animating a roulette Wheel that must:

1. Read from standard input one valid bet on a single number.
2. Randomly select a winning number.
3. Display an animation of the roulette wheel consisting of at least 2 images.
   4.Display the user bet, the winning number and the payout value (calculated on the basis    that each bet value is 1) on the image at the end of the animation.

I have animated my Wheel using a for loop and have a random winner I just require assistance with the user input.

For my user input I have this now thanks to all the comments and the feedback:

```
       char userbet[3];  
       int result1;
       scanf( "%s" , &userbet);
       if(atoi(userbet) >=0 && atoi(userbet) <= 36){result1 = 1;
       printf("you bet on number %s", &userbet);} 
       else {
       printf("please enter a valid bet", &userbet);}
```

This works, I tested several numbers and got the results I wanted. Now can anyone help me with using this to trigger my animation?

Hoping to use 'result' to trigger the animation through an if statement but instead the program skips past this whole section and plays the animation anyway. If anyone has any idea how to force the program to check the stdin console or can see a way around this please help!

I'm a beginner and all comments are valued, thank you for reading and I hope my question doesn't break any rules. Thank you for all the feedback!

If anyone has a better suggestion for the user input I am all ears.

rest of the source code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <gd.h>

    #define USE_GLOBAL_COLORMAP  1
    #define USE_LOCAL_COLORMAP   0

    #define LOOP_ANIMATION_FOREVER  0
    #define DO_NOT_LOOP_ANIMATION  -1
    #define AUTO_FRAME_DISPOSAL     1
    #define ANIMATION_DELAY         1 /* in milliseconds */

    #define IMAGE_WIDTH        640
    #define IMAGE_HEIGHT       720
    #define CIRCLE_DIAMETER    30
    #define MAX_FRAMES_COUNT   70
    #define MOVEMENT_PER_FRAME 10


    int main( void )
    {

      FILE *animatedGIF;
      gdImagePtr frameImage;
      int yellow, black, red, green, brown, darkbrown, gold, silver, white, grey, frameCounter, drawingColor, number, WinningAngle;
      int sliceCounter = 0;
      int sliceStartingAngle = 0;
      int sliceEndingAngle = 0;
      int sliceAngleIncrement = 9;
      int centerPointX = 320;
      int centerPointY = 360;
      int wheelDiameter = 560;
      int insideCoverDiameter = 400;
      int textPositionAngle = 367;
      int textRotationAngle = 270;
      int BallPositionAngle = 0;
      int BallSpeed;
      int Ballroute = 180;
      double textPositionX, textPositionY, BallPositionX, BallPositionY;
      double degreesToRadiansMultiplier = 0.0174532925;
      char *pocketNumbers[] = { "32", "15", "19", "4",  "21", "2",  "25", "17", "34",
                         "6",  "27", "13", "36", "11", "30", "8",  "23", "10",
                         "5",  "24", "16", "33", "1",  "20", "14", "31", "9",
                         "22", "18", "29", "7",  "28", "12", "35", "3",  "26", "0" };                    

      srand( time( 0 ) );
      number = rand();
      number = number % 100;
      number++;
      BallSpeed = number;




      animatedGIF = fopen( "animation.gif", "wb" );
      frameImage = gdImageCreate( IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT );
      gdImageColorAllocate( frameImage, 34, 139, 34 );

     gdImageGifAnimBegin( frameImage, animatedGIF, USE_GLOBAL_COLORMAP,         DO_NOT_LOOP_ANIMATION); 

      for ( frameCounter = 0; frameCounter <= MAX_FRAMES_COUNT; frameCounter++ )
      {
        gdImageDestroy( frameImage );

        frameImage = gdImageCreate( IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT );
        gdImageColorAllocate( frameImage, 34, 139, 34 );
        yellow = gdImageColorAllocate( frameImage, 255, 255, 0 );
        green = gdImageColorAllocate( frameImage,  0, 190, 0  );
        red = gdImageColorAllocate( frameImage, 255, 0, 0 );
        black = gdImageColorAllocate( frameImage, 0, 0, 0 );
        brown = gdImageColorAllocate( frameImage, 222, 184, 135 );
        darkbrown = gdImageColorAllocate( frameImage, 139, 69, 19);
        gold = gdImageColorAllocate( frameImage, 255, 215, 0);
        silver = gdImageColorAllocate( frameImage, 191, 192, 192);
        white = gdImageColorAllocate( frameImage, 255, 255, 255 );
        grey = gdImageColorAllocate( frameImage, 105, 105, 105 );
        gdImageSetThickness( frameImage, 4 );
        gdImageFilledArc(frameImage, centerPointX, centerPointY, 596, 596, 0, 360, brown, gdArc);
        do {

        sliceStartingAngle = sliceEndingAngle;
        sliceEndingAngle = sliceStartingAngle + sliceAngleIncrement;
        textRotationAngle -= sliceAngleIncrement;
        textPositionAngle -= sliceAngleIncrement;

        if ( sliceCounter == 36)
        {
          drawingColor = green;
          sliceEndingAngle += 1;
          textPositionAngle -= 3;

        }
         else if ( (sliceCounter % 2) == 0 )
        {
          drawingColor = red;
          textRotationAngle += 2;

        }
        else
        {
          drawingColor = black;
          sliceEndingAngle += 1;
          textPositionAngle -= 1;
          textRotationAngle -= 1;
        }
        if ( (sliceCounter % 5) == 0 ) sliceEndingAngle += 1;
        if ( (sliceCounter % 7) == 6 ) { textPositionAngle -= 1; textRotationAngle -= 8; }
        if ( (sliceCounter % 13) == 12 ) textPositionAngle -= 1;

        textPositionX = (cos(textPositionAngle * degreesToRadiansMultiplier) * (wheelDiameter / 2.25)) + centerPointX;
        textPositionY = centerPointY - (sin(textPositionAngle * degreesToRadiansMultiplier) * (wheelDiameter / 2.25));

        gdImageFilledArc( frameImage, centerPointX, centerPointY, wheelDiameter, wheelDiameter, sliceStartingAngle, sliceEndingAngle, drawingColor, gdArc ); 

        gdImageStringFT( frameImage, NULL, white, "Vera.ttf", 14, textRotationAngle * degreesToRadiansMultiplier, textPositionX, textPositionY, pocketNumbers[ sliceCounter ] );
        }while (++sliceCounter < 37 );

        gdImageFilledArc(frameImage, centerPointX, centerPointY, 400, 400, 0, 360, grey, gdArc); 
        gdImageFilledArc(frameImage, centerPointX, centerPointY, 320, 320, 0, 360, black, gdArc); 
        gdImageArc(frameImage, centerPointX, centerPointY, 400, 400, 0, 360, gold);
        gdImageFilledArc(frameImage, centerPointX, centerPointY, 100, 100, 0, 360, black, gdArc);
        gdImageFilledArc(frameImage, centerPointX, centerPointY, 20, 20, 0, 360, silver, gdArc);
        gdImageFilledArc(frameImage, centerPointX, 345, 10, 20, 0, 360, silver, gdArc);
        gdImageFilledArc(frameImage, centerPointX, 375, 10, 20, 0, 360, silver, gdArc);
        gdImageFilledArc(frameImage, 335, centerPointY, 20, 10, 0, 360, silver, gdArc);
        gdImageFilledArc(frameImage, 305, centerPointY, 20, 10, 0, 360, silver, gdArc);
        gdImageArc(frameImage, centerPointX, centerPointY, 460, 460, 0, 360, gold);
        gdImageArc(frameImage, centerPointX, centerPointY, 600, 600, 0, 360, darkbrown);

        if ( frameCounter == 70 ) {
        BallPositionX = (cos( degreesToRadiansMultiplier * BallPositionAngle ) * 215) + centerPointX;
        BallPositionY = centerPointY - (sin( degreesToRadiansMultiplier * BallPositionAngle ) * 215);
        gdImageFilledEllipse( frameImage, BallPositionX, BallPositionY, CIRCLE_DIAMETER, CIRCLE_DIAMETER, silver );
        BallPositionAngle = WinningAngle; }

        else if(frameCounter >= 20) {
        BallPositionX = (cos( degreesToRadiansMultiplier * BallPositionAngle ) * Ballroute) + centerPointX;
        BallPositionY = centerPointY - (sin( degreesToRadiansMultiplier * BallPositionAngle ) * Ballroute);
        gdImageFilledEllipse( frameImage, BallPositionX, BallPositionY, CIRCLE_DIAMETER, CIRCLE_DIAMETER, silver ); }

        sliceCounter = 0;
        sliceStartingAngle = 0;
        sliceEndingAngle = 9;
        textPositionAngle = 367;
        textRotationAngle = 270;
        BallPositionAngle = 0;
        sliceStartingAngle += 9 * frameCounter;
        sliceEndingAngle += 9 * frameCounter;
        textPositionAngle -= 9 * (frameCounter + 1);
        textRotationAngle -= 9 * (frameCounter + 1);
        BallPositionAngle += BallSpeed * (frameCounter); 


        gdImageGifAnimAdd( frameImage, animatedGIF, USE_GLOBAL_COLORMAP, 0, 0, ANIMATION_DELAY, AUTO_FRAME_DISPOSAL, NULL ); } 


        //sliceCounter = (WinningAngle / 9);
        //gdImageStringFT( frameImage, NULL, white, "Vera.ttf", 14, 0, centerPointX, centerPointY, pocketNumbers[ sliceCounter ] ); }

      gdImageGifAnimEnd( animatedGIF );
      fclose( animatedGIF );
      gdImageDestroy( frameImage ); }
```

Comment: Did you by any chance mean `>=36` not `<=36` ?

Comment: can you post the rest of the source code?

Comment: I updated my post with the source code for the whole wheel so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you expect to handle input greater than 10 with this code?

```
char userbet[2];        // Only 2 characters!
scanf( "%s" , userbet); // %s means string, which means it ends with a \0 terminator.
```

An input of 10 or greater would look like:

```
[1] [0] [\0-terminator].
```

That is 3 characters!

Comment: So do I change the userbet[2] to userbet[3]?

Comment: If you use `userbet[3]`, ask yourself what happens if a user types in `"1234567"`?? How do you want to handle that?  Ask yourself if `%s` and a character-array is the best tool, or if there is a better tool to use?

Comment: I was planning on using a character array so I can use the 'strncmp' function and compare the user input string with the winning number string.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you read a string when you need a number?

Its better practice to scanf for an int and check if the number complies with your demands.

Atoi might be failing to convert the string and returning a value of 0 or 1...

Try scanfing for %d...

Comment: I tried changing it to &d but it generates -4992 every time now.

Comment: Is this how you do it: int x; scanf("%d", &x);?

Comment: Yeah I changed the s for a d.

Comment: You must have the "&" sign before your int variable in scanf, in your scanf you don't use it since userInput is already a pointer but int is not.